# Restore original text in TDrawGrid while cell is being edited

Tags: delphi, grid

I have a TDrawGrid in Delphi 10.2 with some cells displaying text. The user is allowed to edit these cells. While the user is editing the cell I want to offer the option to programmatically enter pre-defined text into the cell, while remaining in edit mode. (By way of example, the user may wish to enter "Propagate up" or "Propagate down" into the cell. Pressing ^P would change the contents to "Propagate " allowing the user to then add "up" or "down" as appropriate.)

TDrawGrid does not allow access to the InPlaceEditor. Without resorting to sub-classing TDrawGrid (to make InPlaceEditor public, as at least one user has done), does anyone know how this might be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

For those who may follow, the in place editor may be accessed through the grid's Controls property...

```
TInplaceEdit(Grid1.Controls[0]).Text := 'whatever';
```

(Thanks to Chris Luck on one of the Delphi forums http://www.delphigroups.info/2/ec/405543.html)